# r lookup weekly to daily dataset

Tags: r

I have two datasets:

```
date_daily <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-14"), by="days")
result_daily <- runif(14)

df_daily <- data.frame(date_daily, result_daily)
```

> ```
> date_daily     result_daily
> 1  2020-01-01   0.1827247
> 2  2020-01-02   0.8850888
> 3  2020-01-03   0.2254615
> 4  2020-01-04   0.4255329
> 5  2020-01-05   0.3254745
> 6  2020-01-06   0.5452405
> 7  2020-01-07   0.5604055
> 8  2020-01-08   0.2353714
> 9  2020-01-09   0.5555435
> 10 2020-01-10   0.9743918
> 11 2020-01-11   0.9891048
> 12 2020-01-12   0.6198657
> 13 2020-01-13   0.4376414
> 14 2020-01-14   0.6921558
> ```

and

```
date_weekly <- c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-08')
result_weekly <- c(0.8, 0.9)

df_weekly <- data.frame(date_weekly, result_weekly)
```

> ```
> date_weekly     result_weekly
> 1  2020-01-01   0.8
> 2  2020-01-08   0.9
> ```

On the `df_daily` dataframe, I need another column, lets say `weekly_forecast` which gets the data from `df_weekly$result_weekly`. The challange for me is how to relookup the corresponding week without specifying dates with `if/then` function.

Example of how it should look:

> ```
> date_daily      result_daily   weekly_forecast
> 1  2020-01-01   0.1827247      0.8
> 2  2020-01-02   0.8850888      0.8
> 3  2020-01-03   0.2254615      0.8
> 4  2020-01-04   0.4255329      0.8
> ```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest merging the data and as the values for dates are sequences you can fill the variable with `fill()` function from `tidyverse`. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
date_daily <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-14"), by="days")
result_daily <- runif(14)

df_daily <- data.frame(date_daily, result_daily)
#Data 2
date_weekly <- c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-08')
result_weekly <- c(0.8, 0.9)

df_weekly <- data.frame(date_weekly, result_weekly,stringsAsFactors = F)
df_weekly$date_weekly <- as.Date(df_weekly$date_weekly)
#Merge
merged <- merge(df_daily,df_weekly,by.x=c("date_daily"),by.y=c("date_weekly"),all.x=T)
#Now fill
merged %>% fill(result_weekly)
```

Output:

```
   date_daily result_daily result_weekly
1  2020-01-01    0.9532196           0.8
2  2020-01-02    0.4798924           0.8
3  2020-01-03    0.1828868           0.8
4  2020-01-04    0.7816979           0.8
5  2020-01-05    0.6445879           0.8
6  2020-01-06    0.5107246           0.8
7  2020-01-07    0.5826643           0.8
8  2020-01-08    0.5775395           0.9
9  2020-01-09    0.3546509           0.9
10 2020-01-10    0.1400497           0.9
11 2020-01-11    0.1944016           0.9
12 2020-01-12    0.9226711           0.9
13 2020-01-13    0.4646011           0.9
14 2020-01-14    0.1772259           0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

An other solution is to create a `week` variable to merge on:

```
library(lubridate)

df_weekly$week <- week(ymd(df_weekly$date_weekly))
df_daily$week <-  week(ymd(df_daily$date_daily))

merge(df_daily,df_weekly,all = T, on = "week")

   week date_daily result_daily date_weekly result_weekly
1     1 2020-01-01   0.74469462  2020-01-01           0.8
2     1 2020-01-02   0.37656046  2020-01-01           0.8
3     1 2020-01-03   0.05289882  2020-01-01           0.8
4     1 2020-01-04   0.29557015  2020-01-01           0.8
5     1 2020-01-05   0.52228756  2020-01-01           0.8
6     1 2020-01-06   0.11383698  2020-01-01           0.8
7     1 2020-01-07   0.47270121  2020-01-01           0.8
8     2 2020-01-08   0.25473228  2020-01-08           0.9
9     2 2020-01-09   0.80233063  2020-01-08           0.9
10    2 2020-01-10   0.37840717  2020-01-08           0.9
11    2 2020-01-11   0.04052109  2020-01-08           0.9
12    2 2020-01-12   0.10734032  2020-01-08           0.9
13    2 2020-01-13   0.65608993  2020-01-08           0.9
14    2 2020-01-14   0.64426941  2020-01-08           0.9
```